# print column names with alphabetical order summary

Tags: r

I would get

```
> colnames(cdf_LM)
   [1] "MOD_D"        "ID"           "YEAR"         "REGION"       "TOWN_T"       "APT_T"        "PSU"         
   [8] "SEX"          "AGE"          "INCM"         "HO_INCM"      "INCM5"        "HO_INCM5"     "EDU"         
  [15] "OCCP"         "KSTRATA"      "WT_HS"        "WT_ITV"       "WT_EX"        "WT_PFT"       "WT_NTR"      
  [22] "WT_ITVEX"     "WT_TOT"       "WT_PFNT"      "CFAM"         "GENERTN"      "ALLOWNC"      "HOUSE"       
  [29] "HOUSE_PRC"    "HOUSE_YY"     "HOUSE_MM"     "HOUSE_LONG"   "HOUSE_P_YY"   "HOUSE_P_MM"   "LIVE_T"      
  [36] "AINC_UNIT1"   "AINC_1"       "AINC_UNIT2"   "AINC_2"       "AINC"         "SUPRT_1"      "SUPRT_2"     
  [43] "SUPRT_3"      "MARRI_1"      "MARRI_2"      "RELAT"        "TINS"         "NPINS"        "ID_F"
```

Since there are many column names,
can I get a way to sort alphabetically?
for example

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
A.1 B.1
A.2 B.2
A.3 B.3
...
```

Comment: Do you want `cdf_LM[sort(names(cdf_LM))]`?

Comment: Similar, but result of cdf_LM[sort(names(cdf_LM))] to be arranged into column
A, B, C, D, ..
column A would contain colnames that start with A

Comment: I see - seems like you want something like `split(names(cdf_LM), substr(names(cdf_LM), 1, 1))`.